# Verilog: initialization in hierarchical design

Tags: verilog

I have some questions about reg initialization.

1. Can I put Initial blocks in the design? Is that a good way?
2. How to initial regs in my bottom design? Do I need to create ports in each level and give initial value from top to bottom? For each simulation, initial values are different.

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1:**
We recently had a discussion about initial statements on the Electronics forum.

- Initial statements in test benches are normal. In fact without initial statements it becomes a lot more difficult to write test code.
- Initial statements are not possible in ASICs, CPLDs or hard programmed FPGAs.
- You can use initial statements in a most RAM based FPGAs where the state is valid after the FPGA is loaded. However if you would have a 'reset' pin or command that would **not** restore the initial state. As such, the FPGA condition after such a reset could well be different from your start-up state and thus your design might not work correctly.
- There are some cases where an initial state in an actual synthesize-able module is allowed or even mandatory for the module to work. See examples below.

Example 1: You have a divide by two register without reset coded as:

```
divide_by_two <=  ~divide_by_two;
or 
divide_by_two <=  not(divide_by_two);
```

In simulation that will always remain 'X' but in reality it will start in a 0 or 1 conditions and then toggle between the two. To work around the 'X' in simulation you have the set an initial condition. Your code should work independent if the initial condition is '1' or '0'.

Example 2: You have a divide by four register without reset coded as:

```
divide_by_four[1:0] <= {divide_by_four[0],~divide_by_four[1]};
or
divide_by_four[1:0] <= divide_by_four[0] & not(divide_by_four[1]);
```

The reason why this is allowed is that during operation the two registers go through every of the four possible states: 00, 01, 11, 10. It does not matter in which of the four it starts, the sequence will always be repeated. Again to work around the 'XX' in simulation you have the set an initial condition. Your code should work independent if the initial condition is 00, 01, 10 or 11.

A lot of designers feel that, apart for examples like above, the use of initial statements in synthesized code is dangerous and it is better to avoid them.

**Point 2:**
Instead of initial statements you can use a 'reset' signal with the appropriate HDL code to set the start condition. It is normal for the reset to go to every module which has registers.

Comment: For the point 2, Do I need to create input ports like reg_init to assign the initial values from top to bottom? My initial values might be changed when I simulate different scenarios. Is there any better way?

Comment: I have never encountered such a case. Normally if you need different start values they are set by a CPU using a write-bus. If you need to you can either use an include file with defines or you can pass them as parameters. In the latter case you have to pass them throughout the hierarchy. But that still leaves you with the question: what start values will you use in the real code?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your target design.

You can ***usually*** use `initial` blocks with FPGAs. You can initialization the registers in the same module that declares it. Hierarchically assignment is not allowed. You can also initialization registers with a synchronous reset if you add a reset input. Most FPGAs have a limited number of flops with asynchronous reset/preset (if any). Hence `initial` blocks and synchronous resets are the best options FPGA.

ASICs ***typically*** do not synthesize `initial` blocks. Initialization of flops is done with reset condition in synchronous logic. This is commonly an asynchronous reset but not required. In sort, synchronous or asynchronous reset for ASIC.

For both cases, to be synthesizable the initialization value needs to be deterministic and determined by constants. It cannot be derived on an input port or the current state of another register.

It is a good idea to follow these guidelines even if you plan to never synthesize. Otherwise is extra challenging to debug.

Comment: It's not the FPGAs or ASICs that do/don't support `initial` blocks, rather it's a matter of what the tools that are used to translate from HDL code to the target technology make out of them. (But yes, typically tools that are used for FPGAs tend to make something useful from `initial` blocks and tools that are used for ASICs tend not to.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mentions ASICs _typically_ do not support `initial`. I've tweaked my answer to state that FPGAs _usually_ do.